# Почему не запускается скрипт npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

1. в package.json написал скрипт для запуска сервера:

   ...
         "scripts": {
           "start": "NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server",
   ...
2. пишу в консоли npm start получаю ошибку:

   $ npm start

   > cloning-yelp@1.0.0 start c:\OpenServer\domains\cloning-yelp
   >   NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server

   "NODE_ENV" ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒७▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒譥▒
   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒ᯮ▒▒塞▒▒ ▒ணࠬ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ 䠩▒▒▒.

   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
   npm ERR! node v6.2.0
   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! cloning-yelp@1.0.0 start: `NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the cloning-yelp@1.0.0 start script 'NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the cloning-yelp package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs cloning-yelp
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls cloning-yelp
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!     c:\OpenServer\domains\cloning-yelp\npm-debug.log

Но если прописываю команду в консоли напрямую всё работает:

```
$ NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server
Listening at http://localhost:3000
webpack built a2a647e1f21960bcfc8e in 2380ms
```

В чём может быть дело? Что я упустил? Вот лог npm:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.9
3 info using node@v6.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~prestart: cloning-yelp@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~start: cloning-yelp@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;c:\OpenServer\domains\cloning-yelp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\user\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\mingw32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\usr\bin;C:\Users\user\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;node_modules\.bin;C:\OpenServer\domains\node_modules\.bin;C:\OpenServer\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\program files (x86)\smartgit\jre\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\usr\bin\core_perl
10 verbose lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~start: CWD: c:\OpenServer\domains\cloning-yelp
11 silly lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server' ]
12 silly lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle cloning-yelp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: cloning-yelp@1.0.0 start: `NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:245:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid cloning-yelp@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd c:\OpenServer\domains\cloning-yelp
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.2.0
20 error npm  v3.8.9
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error cloning-yelp@1.0.0 start: `NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the cloning-yelp@1.0.0 start script 'NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the cloning-yelp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs cloning-yelp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls cloning-yelp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно в Windows нужно попробовать так

```
 ...  
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development && hjs-dev-server"
 } 
 ...
```

можно использовать `cross-env`:

```
npm i -D cross-env
```

Затем в `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development hjs-dev-server"
}
```